# How can I convert Row to Table Column in Oracle SQL Output?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle12c

I want to convert my oracle sql output to table data row to Column.

My SQL output like

```
ITEM    | RESULT
-----------------
Shell   | 296.5
-----------------
Shell   | 299.8
-----------------
Shell   | 311
-----------------
Shell   | 289
-----------------
Lining  | 301.33
-----------------
Lining  | 296.5
-----------------
Lining  | 299
-----------------
```

But I want the output like -

```
Shell    |   Lining
----------------------
296.5    |  301.33
----------------------
299.8    |  296.5
----------------------
311      |  299
----------------------
289      |  0 --
```

### If any item have less result then will be fillup with Zero(0)

So please suggest me the sql code that will fulfill my requirment. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Pivot using row number so that you don't lose any value in your grouping while using max.

```
with cte as (
select 'Shell' as Item,   '296.5'  as Resultn from dual  union all 
select 'Shell' as Item,   '299.8'  as Resultn from dual  union all 
select 'Shell' as Item,   '311'    as Resultn from dual  union all 
select 'Shell' as Item,   '289'    as Resultn from dual  union all 
select 'Lining' as Item,  '301.33' as Resultn from dual  union all 
select 'Lining' as Item,  '296.5'  as Resultn from dual  union all 
select 'Lining' as Item,  '299'    as Resultn from dual   )

select nvl(Shell,0) Shell, nvl(Lining,0) Lining from (
select  c.item, c.Resultn, row_number() over (partition by Item order by Resultn) rownumn   
from cte c 
) z 
pivot 
(
max(Resultn) 
for item in ('Shell' as Shell  ,'Lining' as Lining ));
```

Output:

```
SHELL   LINING
289     296.5
296.5   299
311      0
299.8   301.33
```

Answer (score 0):

`PIVOT` is the right thing that you are looking for.
take a look here:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

Comment: With pivot we need to apply a data aggregation function, don't think that will work here, as aggregation is not required

Comment: @peeyushsingh if the group by applies on a unique field it can fully fill the requirement

Comment: hmm, yes might work, but then again are we sure that results column would be unique for each item?

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional aggregation

```
select max(case when ITEM='Shell' then RESULT end) as shell,
max(case when ITEM='Lining' then RESULT end) as Lining
from 
  ( select *,row_number() over(partition by item order by result) rn from 
    tablename
  )A
group by rn
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do pivot, as provided below. But, you need aggregate function for the pivot. You need to select one more column from the table, for grouping.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT Item, Result
FROM Table1) 
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Result) FOR ITEM IN ('SHELL' Shell,'LINING' Lining) 
)
```